# Delete a row from a table which has a fk with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys, delete-row

Is there a simple way of deleting a row from a table without previously deleting from other table the rows involved in the foreign key constraint with hibernate?

Comment: you can use CascadeType.delete

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

Imagine you have the following class

```
public class User
{

 @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)  
 private Account bankAccount; // FK toward Accounttable
}
```

for example when you remove your user you want to remove the account record associated with it.
so adding the CascadeType.REMOVE in your relation will also remove the related entity.

and then:

```
session.delete(user); // will remove account associated
```

You can also put CascadeType.ALL instead of remove if you need more control for your account class from your User class.
Hope that's help